# Binding IDataErrorInfo to window IsEnabled button property

Tags: .net, wpf, validation, binding, isenabled

I have a WPF sub window with some input controls that the user has to correctly fill before pressing Ok button.

I have already implemented the interface **IDataErrorInfo** to validate all properties bound to UI Controls.

Now I would like that the **IsEnabled** property of Ok button is **True** only if ALL controls are valid, otherwise it has to be set to **False**.

It should be easy but I cannot find the correct solution. Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Ciao ;-)

I think you could bind the `IsEnabled` property of the button to (e.g.) the `IDataErrorInfo.Error` property of your data through a IValueConverter (that you have to implement) that converts from `string` to `bool` (e.g if the value if `String.Empty` than return `true`).

Another solution is to use `Command`s and have this logic enclosed in the `CanExecute`: in this way you just have to associate the `Command` with your `Button`.
HTH

Comment: @Fabrizio
thank you Fabrizio, I'll try your suggestions and come back with the result as soon as possible ;)

Comment: I tried the implementation using the IDataErrorInfo.Error property. Practically I have bound that to the IsEnable button property with the converter, but it does not work. Probably I should implement an event and bound it in the button triggers. Not sure about it.